# React, Express - GET data from database return array of objects, but I cant access to any object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, express, object

I have react app that uses Express to communicate with API. I use GET method to fetch data from db, and it goes well, code for fetching looks like this one:

```
const posts = [];

fetch(URL)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(jsondata => posts.push(jsondata));
```

When I execute console.log(posts); it gives me this output in console:
[output](https://ibb.co/qgKjc02)

It is exactly what I want to fetch, but I cant access to any of those objects in array.
Some solutions I have already tried for fetching first one post from array are:

```
console.log(posts[0]["post"]);
console.log(posts[0][0]["posts"]); 
console.log(posts[0].post); 
console.log(posts[0][0]);
```

I searched a lot about array objects in JS and JSX also tried some "for loop" solutions but nothing works for me. What I want to achieve is to make array of strings respectively order from fetching, so I can show its value in some html tags. For example I want to make array of string looks like this then I will use for loop to iterate over every single post and show it in html:

```
['This is my first post', 'This is my second post', 'This is my third post']
```

Please help me handle this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `posts` is a variable and not part of component state.

Try something like this:

```
state = {
 posts: []
}
~~~~
.then(jsondata => this.setState({posts: jsondata}));
```

Further, if you want to display your posts data in a list you can do so inside the return statement like this:

```
return (
        <ul>
            {this.state.posts.map(element => {
              return  <li key={element.post}>{element.post}</li>
                }
        </ul>

)
```

Comment: "TypeError: this.state.posts is not a function" in second part of code

Comment: This is constructor: constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          posts: []
        };
    }

Comment: good catch. You want to add `.map` after posts but before the parens. As far as initializing state, both ways (with or w/o constructor) are valid.

Comment: It solve error, but returns empty <ul></ul> tag in html. I used this code for fetching: componentDidMount(){
    fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsondata => this.setState({posts: jsondata}))
    }

Comment: In console one error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Can you update your question with an image of the error and snippet of the code. It looks like it's syntax related so could be a typo after the update.

Comment: It was my fault, URL variable was outside of componentDidMount() function. I just moved it inside and now it works like a charm. Thank you Hyetigran so much for your time and knowledge. This gives me a lot of motivation to keep working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

You need `map` and then `console.log` from inside the Promise chain

```js
fetch(URL)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => data.map(({ post }) => post))
.then(console.log);
```

Comment: Returns empty array with length 0, even if I try console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

When you do posts.push(jsondata) you are actually pushing all the array, so your posts variable will end up looking like this

```js
[[{},{},{}]]
```

If you want to push the items individually one option is to use the spread operator

```js
posts.push(...jsondata);
```

so you get

```js
[{},{},{}]
```

then you can do `posts[0].post`

Comment: Now I see, [{},{},{}] in console as array, but it returns TypeError: posts[0] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This example using Hooks and useEffect

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyPost = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('url')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonData => setPost([...jsonData]));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {post.length > 0 ? (
        <ol>
          {post.map(p => (
            <li key={p.replace(/' '/g, '')}>{p}</li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      ) : (
        <h1>No post Available</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyPost;
```